# What's the difference between "isn't it wrong?" and "is it not wrong?"

Tags: grammar, meaning

Recently I hear them a lot in movies and I don't know which one is right. Help me plz

Comment: Both are correct.  The first uses a contraction, the second doesn't.

Comment: My guess would be that you hear "Is it not wrong?" in historical dramas or fantasy films where some characters speak in a formal, 'old-fashioned' style. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

Is it not wrong? ➜ Isn't it wrong?

Isn't is a contraction of 'is not'.

'Isn't it wrong?' is usually used in spoken English.
'Is it not wrong?' is usually used in writing.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same. There is a nearly trivial difference in emphasis. Because the word that comes in with negation requires you to pay more attention, the word with the "not" gets slightly more emphasis. The difference is very slight except in certain very local [dialects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxxWMkxgZ6s) where negation is pressed into the job of extra strong emphasis. In such dialects it would be not not emphatic.

"Isn't it wrong" is a contraction of "is not it wrong." So in this case the "not" is with the "is." So the emphasis is on the "is."

"Is it not wrong" has the negation on the "wrong." So the emphasis is on the "wrong."